# How to use a library if it's been used internally by another library?

Tags: ios, xcode, sdwebimage

I have been using cisco library "libAssistSDK.a" which is part of cisco remote expert mobile service and apparently this library uses sdwebimage internally. So now I have a lot of duplicates here and there.

What should I do ?

example code:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SDImageCache._ioQueue in:
/Users/********/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-ezewidnzfmvgaqhkczrmaahscmak/Build/Intermediates/appname.build/Debug-iphoneos/appname.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SDImageCache.o
```

similarly others include

```
Remote Expert Mobile/expert_assist_iOS_SDK-10/assist_ios_sdk/libAssistSDK.a(SDWebImageDownloader.o)
Remote Expert Mobile/expert_assist_iOS_SDK-10/assist_ios_sdk/libAssistSDK.a(SDWebImageDownloaderOperation.o)
Remote Expert Mobile/expert_assist_iOS_SDK-10/assist_ios_sdk/libAssistSDK.a(SDWebImagePrefetcher.o)
Remote Expert Mobile/expert_assist_iOS_SDK-10/assist_ios_sdk/libAssistSDK.a(SDWebImageManager.o)


ld: 65 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: are you linking against sdwebimage on your own, or another library is doing this for you?

Comment: Yeah I added both SDWebimage and libAssistSDK.a to the project !

Comment: why don't you remove sdwebimage if that's the reason for the duplicated symbols?

Comment: I am using SDWebImage in the app, specifically UIImageView+WebCache  that uses SDWebImageManager. I tried to rename the duplicates variables, but It seems like it's a hideous process and will take on forever !

Comment: I'm not familiar with SDWebImage, but if it comes in the form of a static library you can try to remove that as you get the symbols from assistSDK, if it comes in source format only keep the headers, .h files and delete any implementation files (.m, .mm, .c) files, the symbols should again come from assistSDK. If assistSDK and sdwebimage use different versions of the imeplementations you have a problem :)

Comment: Alright thanks I deleted the .m files , hopefully something good will happen :)